# How to number occurrences of a column value in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
ID | PODUCT
1  | apple
2  | apple
3  | banana
4  | apple
5  | banana
```

If I use:

```
SELECT S.ID, S.PRODUCT, C.cnt
FROM table1 S
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PRODUCT, COUNT(PRODUCT) AS cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY PRODUCT
) C
    ON S.PRODUCT = C.PRODUCT
```

I'll get this:

```
ID | PODUCT  | cnt
1  | apple   | 3
2  | apple   | 3   
3  | banana  | 2
4  | apple   | 3
5  | banana  | 2
```

But what I need is this:

```
ID | PODUCT  | cnt
1  | apple   | 1
2  | apple   | 2   
4  | apple   | 3
3  | banana  | 1
5  | banana  | 2
```

So I guess I really need NOT the count of occurrences but the number of occurrences; I hope that makes sense. Oh , and I am using DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
select s.*, count(*) over (partition by poduct order by id) as cnt
from table1 s;
```

However, this would required really `row_number()` instead of `count()`, but the idea would be same.

In other way you can use correlated subquery :

```
select s.*, 
       (select count(*)
        from table1 s1
        where s1.poduct = s.poduct and s1.id <= s.id
       ) as cnt
from table1 s;
```

Answer (score 1):

`ROW_NUMBER` should work here:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    PODUCT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PODUCT ORDER BY ID) cnt
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    PODUCT, ID;
```

If, for some reason, you can't use analytic functions, here is an alternative which does not use them:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    PODUCT,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t1.PODUCT = t2.PODUCT AND t2.ID <= t1.ID) cnt
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    PODUCT, ID;
```

### Demo

The demo is for the second query in MySQL, but should run on DB2 with either no or very little modification.

Comment: Note that putting the aggregate in the `SELECT` list **may** cause that query to be RBAR'd, which may cause a performance penalty.  If you're counting the majority of the rows in the table, this may run slower than doing it as a correlated join.